# Python regex non greedy

Tags: regex, python-3.x

as we know the python '?' quantifier is consider a lazy quantifier and then should gives us the shortest match, but in my example i am getting the second match(second_occurrence), instead of the first match(first_occurrence)

```
content = "this is how we want that first_occurrence over there but that second_occurrence it is 
always wrong when "
match = re.search(r"^this .* that (?P<occurrence>.*?) ", content)
print(match.groupdict())
```

Comment: >>> match = re.search(r"`^(this .* that )(?P<occurrence>.*?) `", content)
>>> print(match.group(1))
this is how we want that first_occurrence over there but that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your expression `"^this .* that (?P<occurrence>.*?) "` the first `.*` is greedy, so that it will match all the way to the last `that`.

Change your example to:

```
import re

content = "this is how we want that first_occurrence over there but that second_occurrence it is always wrong when "
match = re.search(r"^this .*? that (?P<occurrence>.*?) ", content)
print(match.groupdict())
```

This prints:

```
{'occurrence': 'first_occurrence'}
```